# mongoid unique index allowed duplicate values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection that has a username as a field. The Model defines this field to be unique. However I was able to insert a duplicate value in the database.

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  field :username
  index({ username: 1 } , { unique: true })
end
```

The Collection however has 2 usernames that are the same

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "50b3b323421aa95da6000004" ),
  "username" : "marceloreuse" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId( "50b3b567421aa93d84000002" ),
  "username" : "marceloreuse" }
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: your example also shows the same exact ObjectId's - is that correct or a copy/paste oversight?

Comment: my bad... that was a copy paste issue

Comment: Out of curiosity - this is not a sharded colleciton, is it?

Comment: no, its a normal collection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would double check your indexes - from the console try `db.collection.getIndexes()` and make sure your index is present.

In case you missed it, Mongoid doesn't auto build the index because you specified it - you need to run the included: `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`.

Comment: However, mongoid is still not throwing an error when adding a duplicate entry. The entry is not added, but mongoid is not giving any errors.

Comment: That's due to the default `write concern` in MongoDB - the driver won't wait for a response - meaning you need to either call `getLastError` or change your persistence settings `persist_in_safe_mode`.  Check out [Mongoid: Persistence - Safe Mode](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/persistence/safe_mode.html).